# How many players In a day for a CS:GO server

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

How many unique players online PER DAY does typically a CS:GO server, that usually have around 20-30 players online, recieve?

Or a similar game

Comment: It depends on too much parameters to give you an answer for that e.g. Which country, which provider, which time of the year, how long does every single player stay, will cheaters join who scare other players etc.etc.... just to name a few

Comment: Yeah I understand it can vary much but is it like 100 a day or more like 1000 a day? give me some examples.

Comment: I can't give you examples.. let's say always 20 ppl are on your server.. well 1player could change every 10 seconds or every 2 hours.. just that would make a huge difference

Comment: It's also a very big difference if it's a community map server, a public server or a ranked server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the average playtime of a single player, you can calculate it. For example, if it is half an hour, there are 25 * (24/0.5) = **1200** distinct players online.

I expect the playtime to be somewhat larger, say 2 hours. In that case, there will be roughly 25 * (24/2) = **300** distinct players every day.

If you guess the playtime correctly, you can estimate the number of players each day.

For clarification: the 25 is the average number of players. You said 20-30, so 25 is the average. 24 is the amount of hours per day. The last number is the average playtime per session (0.5 or 2 in my examples).

Comment: Yea maybe thats the best answer I can get. I was hoping for someone who has had that kind of servers to give examples. Because I guess the avarage playtime shouldn't vary THAT much. Thanks for the answer